# GitLab CI "when: never" under "rules" doesn't stop pipeline from triggering

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

GitLab v. Enterprise Edition 15.0.5-ee
I have some stages defined and I need rules that would work like a conjunction.
But I have a problem that simply put:

```
rules:
 - if: ! A
   when: never
 - if: B
```

doesn't work (like it should according to https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html):
it runs a pipeline despite `(! A)` being true

but

```
rules:
 - if: A && B
```

does work (pipeline doesn't run). And second options is not preferable and in other case I have with `exists` it's not possible (correct me if I'm wrong).

**Is there a way to work around it?**

### EDIT 1:

ok I worked around the exists (checking if variable is null) part but I still want to have reusable code.

I'm using reference:

```
.rules:
  rules:
    - if: ! A
      when: never
    - exists:
        - "$ex"
      when: never

rules:
    - !reference [ .rules, rules ]
    - if: $var =~ /^.*abcd.*$/
```

because aliases and anchors don't seem to work here. And if I want this structure then I figured that I need this `when: never` part for it to work. Therefore the original question about it. Without reference it doesn't work either so it doesn't matter unless I can do something to inject the rules in an `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the boolean not operator does not exist, see [this comment](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/206960#note_814219180).
Try

```yaml
rules:
 - if: A != true
   when: never
 - if: B
```

Comment: yeah, I refactored the A condition and it's working. That was the issue. Thanks